# Nifi GetSQS Access Denied - AWS Simple Queue Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, apache-nifi

I am facing some trouble getting the GetSQS processor in Nifi to interface with the Simple Queue Service in AWS.

I have an S3 bucket that sends its events to an SQS Queue and the SQS Queue successfully receives the events/messages from the S3 bucket.

I also have a Linux ec2 instance(with a public IP address) running with Nifi installed on it and it has a GetSQS processor that polls this SQS Queue but every time I run the processor, I get an error saying that the access to the queue is denied,
[image]

I have tried adding the Public/Private IP address of the ec2 instance to the permissions in the SQS Queue as well but to no avail. *(The Access & Secret Key are also correctly typed in the Nifi settings for GetSQS)*
[image]

The same error does not seem to go away no matter what I try to do!

What could I be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is a 403 so probably something to do with the permissions. Can you check the `Access Key` & `Secret Key` property and make sure the user associated with the access keys have read privilege on your queue?

Comment: The configuration of `GetSQS` and the error log from `nifi-app.log` would help.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I generated a new set of access keys for my user and used those in the GetSQS and everything started working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It is a 403 so probably something to do with the permissions. Check the Access Key & Secret Key property and make sure the user associated with the access keys have read privilege on your queue"

I generated a new set of access keys for my user and used those in the GetSQS and everything started working.